# Estimating aspect ratio of a convex hull

Tags: python, geometry

What would be the best way to approximate the aspect ratio of a convex hull in Python? I have already tried doing this by fitting the vertices of the convex hull with an ellipse and taking the ratio of the semi- and major-axis. The results are not satisfactory though, so I'm now looking into deriving the aspect ratio directly from the convex hull. Any ideas or solutions would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean with aspect ratio in this context and how do you want to derive it from the convex hull directly?

Comment: How do you define the aspect ratio of a convex hull? Do you want to allow different angles, so you can get the aspect ratio of a rotated rectangle? If you just want to use 0° and 90° for the axes, the aspect ratio is easy to compute.

Comment: By 0 and 90 degrees, do you mean finding the aspect ratio based as the following? 1) Find the major axis in the convex hull (longest possible path in convex hull through the centroid) and 2) measure minor axis which is orthogonal to the major axis. If that's the case, then it should work.

Comment: That's not what I meant with 0° and 90° (which is just to look at the x-axis range and y-axis range of hull points, i.e. enclose the hull in an axis-parallel rectangle). But you give a definition of what you might be looking for, together with an algorithm (which might or might not be optimal).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, you'd find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of the point cloud.  The aspect ratio is the ratio of the largest to smallest eigenvalues.

As an example for a bunch of random points (you'd just apply the same thing to your convex hull, only using the vertices):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random data
num = 100
xy = np.random.random((2,num)) + 0.01 * np.arange(num)

eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(xy))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
x,y = xy
center = xy.mean(axis=-1)
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.plot(x,y, 'ro')
    ax.axis('equal')

for val, vec in zip(eigvals, eigvecs.T):
    val *= 2
    x,y = np.vstack((center + val * vec, center, center - val * vec)).T
    ax2.plot(x,y, 'b-', lw=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. I'm still testing this code on my data, but so far the results are good. Thanks!